# Gradle: Make "test" source set depend on "main" source set

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Here is my project structure:

[image: IDEA Gradle project structure]

It is the default project structure created by Intellij IDEA for Kotlin projects built with Gradle. For some reason `main` source set is not set as a dependency for `test` source set, making it impossible to write unit tests. I can manually add this dependency in IDEA's "module settings", but every time there is a Gradle refresh this setting goes away.

My guess is that when Gradle is used, IDEA module settings completely copy Gradle settings, so in order to make the dependency persistent, it has to be added to `build.gradle`. What would the syntax be?

Comment: What version of idea and kotlin do you use? I would ask quesiton on JetBrains issue tracker

Comment: @EugenMartynov IDEA is 2016.1.2. Kotlin is 1.0.2, I guess... I have `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.2` and `kotlin-stdlib:1.0.2` listed in Gradle dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The `test` source set already depends on the `main` source set by default. Something is mostly likely wrong with your IntelliJ configuration, but it's not possible to know what without looking at the project.